# How can I make the value of a textbox mulitiple srtings from multiple cells?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I format this correctly. I might be really confused but I just can't remember how I had done this in the past.

```
FndRng.Offset(0, 10).Value = cboStatus.Value&" "&txtDateOfDeparture.Value&" "&through&" "&txtDateOfReturn
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Put space between `&` and anything else:

```
FndRng.Offset(0, 10).Value = cboStatus.Value & " " & txtDateOfDeparture.Value & " " & through & " " & txtDateOfReturn
```

Comment: Oh my I was so close! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You miss spaces

`FndRng.Offset(0, 10).Value = cboStatus.Value & " " & txtDateOfDeparture.Value & " " & through & " " & txtDateOfReturn`